# Should we share articles written for SEO purpose on social media and other social bookmarking websites

Tags: seo

Like we used to share all blogs written anywhere for purpose of seo and same for PR but I am not sure about should we do the same for articles written for SEO or not on social media and social bookmarking websites?

Does anybody has idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

If you share same article on different Social Bookmarking sites, it is a bad technique. If Google find your website's link in duplicate contents then it will affect your website.  Some Bookmarking websites have been penalized by Google so if you share your articles there it will harm your website. So avoid sharing articles on Social Bookmarking websites. If you wish to share your articles on Social media sites, just write few sentence and let users to click read more option to come to your website.

Comment: thanks. But sharing blog is good for SEO right? or we should stop doing that also?

Comment: @Abhi If you share your blog posts on various sharing sites then it will not be good. Stop doing that.